# Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit

Tags: editor, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=15.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' or one of its dependencies.
and below is my webconfig 
    `<configuration>
          <configSections>
            <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
            <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
            <section name="ajaxControlToolkit" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxControlToolkitConfigSection, AjaxControlToolkit" />
          </configSections>
          <system.web>
            <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1">
              <runtime>
                <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
                  <dependentAssembly>
                    <assemblyIdentity name="AjaxControlToolkit" publicKeyToken="28f01b0e84b6d53e" culture="neutral" />
                    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-15.1.2.0" newVersion="15.1.2.0" />
                  </dependentAssembly>
                </assemblyBinding>
              </runtime>
              <ajaxControlToolkit htmlSanitizer="AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditor.Sanitizer.DefaultHtmlSanitizer, AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditor.Sanitizer" />
            </configuration>`

Comment: and i  add two refrences that is ajaxcontroltoolkit and htmleditor sanitizer

Answer (score 1):

You have

```xml
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-15.1.2.0" newVersion="15.1.2.0" />
```

in your Web.config. Remove it as it prevents v 15.1.3.0 from loading.

But I strongly advise you to remove *runtime* section completely.

Comment: when i build my project i found this info: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1697,5): warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.

Comment: How do you install AjaxControlToolkit dll to your project (NuGet package or something else)?

Comment: i have already intall through setup and include in my IDE when ever i select ajax tool the Ajaxcontroltoolkit.dll added with it self

Comment: You can reinstall it with NuGet to get fine version control in your project. However, did this Web.config change eliminate runtime error?